# How do I have a child process write back to the STDIN of its parent in PHP?

Tags: php, unix, stdin

In PHP, is there a way to have a child process forked off with `pcntl_fork()` write data directly back to its parent's stdin? I don't mean with a separate pipe--the stdin resource itself? (It has to be stdin because, in short, what the parent is doing won't work right unless it can bind its own stdin to incoming data directly--a separate pipe won't work.) As in:

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if (!$pid) {
  // do fun child process stuff
  // write data back to parent's STDIN
}
```

Comment: This is a tricky one! I was halfway through and answer when I realized it wasn't going to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux (don't know how prevalent this would be for Unix in general), a process' stdin can be gotten at via `/proc/$PID/fd/0` (as well as stdout/stderr at 1 & 2 rather than 0)

Comment: On my ubuntu desktop it's `/proc/$pid/fd/0`

Comment: Sadly, that only works as root. Is there a way to do it without requiring the user to be root?

Comment: Odd, the pty should be owned by the same uid as the process it represents.

Comment: Ah, you appear to be right. Your answer is correct; my approach is just wrong. :-P Thanks for your help!